# How to convert Object to Xml in mule with JodaTime support?

Tags: java, mule, jodatime

I'm trying to convert an object to xml in mule, using the component of mule Object-To-XML. However, my object has a jodatime property, and because of that mule is returning an object of jodatime. But, that is not what I'm expecting. I'm excpeting a date instead of the whole object of jodatime. Below is what mule is returning:

```
<date>
            <iMillis>1449676220125</iMillis>
            <iChronology class="org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology" resolves-to="org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology$Stub" serialization="custom">
                <org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology_-Stub>
                    <org.joda.time.UTCDateTimeZone resolves-to="org.joda.time.DateTimeZone$Stub" serialization="custom">
                        <org.joda.time.DateTimeZone_-Stub>
                            <string>UTC</string>
                        </org.joda.time.DateTimeZone_-Stub>
                    </org.joda.time.UTCDateTimeZone>
                </org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology_-Stub>
            </iChronology>
</date>
```

However, I want something similar to

```
<date>2015-12-16T16:20:30.659-02:00</date>
```

**Question** : What should I do to convert jodatime correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching on stackoverflow, I found the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434242/xstreams-jodatime-local-date-display)

So, to solve the problem, you should:

1- Create the class suggested on the answer to the question posted above
2- On the connector Object-To-XML, you should add the Converter, which is the class you have just created.

After that, the XML will output the way it supposed to be.